# Plotly choropleth without borders

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly in Python to create a choropleth of US counties colored by some categorical variable. Because counties are so small, the border lines between dominate the image. How can I get rid of them (or set their width to zero)?

Code and output so far (using random data):

Plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ltp.png

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

#Read county geography
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    buf = response.read()
    counties = json.loads(buf.decode('utf-8'))

#Create random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(99999, 1),columns=["val"])
df['category']=df['val']>1
df['fips'] = list(range(1,100000))

#Graph
fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='category',
scope="usa")
fig.show()
```

Comment: [County Choropleth Figure Factory](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/)Wouldn't this official manual be helpful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should work:

```
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0)
```

https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-state-lines-to-county-level-geojson-based-choropleth/36269

Answer (score 3):

I was able to set the line width to 0 by switching to plotly.graph_objects.Choropleth (the lower level version of plotly_express.choropleth). Unfortunately this still produces lines or spaces between the counties, but they are thinner which is good enough for my purpose. Thanks to [r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners) for the pointer.

Output:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCjiu.png)

Code (continuing from the question):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Choropleth(
    locations = df['fips'],
    z = df['category'].astype(int),
    locationmode = 'geojson-id',
    geojson = counties,
    marker = dict(line=dict(width=0))
))

fig.update_layout(
    geo_scope='usa'
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify:

```
fig['layout']['geo']['subunitcolor']='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

This sets the bordercolor to full transparency so they'll appear non-existing:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

#Read county geography
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    buf = response.read()
    counties = json.loads(buf.decode('utf-8'))

#Create random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(99999, 1),columns=["val"])
df['category']=df['val']>1
df['fips'] = list(range(1,100000))

#Graph
fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='category',
scope="usa")

fig['layout']['geo']['subunitcolor']='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
fig.show()
```